# Keeping WebSockets Connection Alive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I am building an app that needs to continuously (24/7) keep a connection open to a WebSockets server.

My current idea is to spin up an AWS EC2 instance and use this as the WebSockets client. Is this a good idea or is there a better way to do approach this problem?

Comment: Yes that's fine - what else were you thinking maybe?

Comment: Something with serverless and AWS Lambdas...

Comment: Lambdas are there for short lived request and responses - you need something 24/7 so you actually need a server in the real sense.